# I can not boot from any device except hdd

Tags: system-installation, windows-7

My Notebook does not execute any Bootable DVD or USB at all. But Notebook is running with con Windows. I have asked this question some people, and they told me my Notebook is not ok, it is an old one.
I want to know if I can Install Ubuntu from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Your notebook can't be that old that it can't boot from USB or optical disc.

Go into your BIOS settings and check the boot order of your system, or see if there is a key you can press during the POST process (Power On Self Test, usually when the manufacturer logo appears on-screen) that will bring up a boot device menu to choose from.

For example, on Lenovo PC's, you can press the F12 key repeatedly on the logo screen until a boot menu appears and you can choose to boot from HDD, optical drive or USB stick/HDD if one was detected. On other brands like HP, ASRock or Gigabyte it's sometimes F2 or F10 or F11. Samsung laptops typically use the ESC key.